# styling wordpress posts loop

Tags: php, wordpress, loops

I've been trying to edit the code for the blog page of wordpress. I have 14 posts and I've set the page to display 5 posts per page. However, it's not working. The first 5 posts displayed just fine, but when you click on "Older Entries", there's nothing. I was trying to make it display 5 posts per page. Here's the code:

```
<div id="blog_content_row">

    <div class="container">

        <div class="row">

            <div class="article editable">

                <div>

                    <?php



                    // Title on some archive views

                    get_template_part( 'parts/title', 'archive');



                    // display featured sometimes

                    if (!is_paged() && is_home()) {

                        $original_query = $wp_query;

                        $wp_query = null;

                        $wp_query = new WP_Query(array('posts_per_page' => 5, 'meta_key' => 'featured_post', 'meta_value' => 'true', 'post__not_in' => get_option( 'sticky_posts' )));

                        if ($wp_query->have_posts()) {

                        } else {

                            $wp_query = null;

                            $wp_query = new WP_Query(array('posts_per_page' => 5, 'post__not_in' => get_option( 'sticky_posts' )));

                        }

                        if (have_posts()) {

                            while (have_posts()) {

                                the_post();

                                $nimbus_feature_id = $post->ID;

                                get_template_part( 'parts/blog', 'featured');

                            }

                        } else {

                            // get_template_part( 'parts/error', 'no_results');

                        }

                        get_template_part( 'parts/blog', 'pagination');

                        $wp_query = null;

                        $wp_query = $original_query;

                        wp_reset_postdata();

                    }



                    // display author stuff here

                    if (is_author()) {

                        get_template_part( 'parts/bio');

                    }


                    ?>

                </div>

            </div>



        </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

Could you let me know what's wrong? I think it might have something to do with $wp_query. The webpage in question is http://disa.com.sv/constructora/?page_id=10.

Comment: Do you know wordpress template hierarchy?

Comment: It looks like if your page is paginated then nothing will happen, as it does not meet this criteria: `if (!is_paged() && is_home()) {` and you have no else clause.

Comment: I replaced  '(!is_paged() && is_home())' with '(have_posts())' and it's kinda working now, but it's only displaying 10 posts instead of 14 posts. It seems like the coded is somehow coded to display if there's at least 5 posts no matter how many posts there are. Do I change it to 'posts_per_page' =5?

Answer (score 0):

Found an answer. It's not in the code. The code is fine. What's important is the functions.php.

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/181487/archive-page-limiting-posts-per-page

I edited it and it work now.

However the problem is that it kept displaying the same 5 posts instead of 14 different posts. Help?